# Axis Tick Mark Labels Disappear When Main and x/y Label Titles Added

Tags: r

My tick mark labels are present before I add titles, but they disappear once titles are added and I can't figure it out. I've tried changing margins and x/y label positions. I'm using R.

```
    boxplot(TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`1`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`2`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`3`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`4`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`5`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`6`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`7`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`8`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`9`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`10`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`11`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`12`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`13`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`14`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`15`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`16`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`17`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`18`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`19`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`20`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`21`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`22`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`23`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`24`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`25`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`26`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`27`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`28`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`29`,
    TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`30`,TrailDailyAir_Boxplots$`31`,
    xlab="Day", ylab="ppb", main="Hourly ppb of SO2 in October 2015")
    par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,2.1)+.1, mgp=c(3,1,0))
    abline(h=70, col="red")
    text(7,225,"CCME Guideline = 70ppb",col="red")
```

[image: Before x/y/main labels]

[image: After x/y/main labels]

Comment: you can save yourself a lot of typing `boxplot(TrailDailyAir_Boxplots[as.character(1:31)])` or `boxplot(TrailDailyAir_Boxplots)` if you want to do all columns. typically you want to set all of your `par`s before starting the plot as they can affect or restart the drawing area

Comment: doi.. Much appreciated, I'm still learning the basics over here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to insert each individual label, but there must be a more efficient method.

```
mtext("1",1,.5,at=1,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("2",1,.5,at=2,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("3",1,.5,at=3,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("4",1,.5,at=4,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("5",1,.5,at=5,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("6",1,.5,at=6,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("7",1,.5,at=7,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("8",1,.5,at=8,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("9",1,.5,at=9,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("10",1,.5,at=10,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("11",1,.5,at=11,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("12",1,.5,at=12,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("13",1,.5,at=13,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("14",1,.5,at=14,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("15",1,.5,at=15,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("16",1,.5,at=16,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("17",1,.5,at=17,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("18",1,.5,at=18,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("19",1,.5,at=19,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("20",1,.5,at=20,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("21",1,.5,at=21,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("22",1,.5,at=22,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("23",1,.5,at=23,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("24",1,.5,at=24,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("25",1,.5,at=25,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("26",1,.5,at=26,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("27",1,.5,at=27,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("28",1,.5,at=28,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("29",1,.5,at=29,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("30",1,.5,at=30,las=1,cex=1)
mtext("31",1,.5,at=31,las=1,cex=1)
```

[After inserting tick mark labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izkDA.png)